# Traverse to an element and add a class to it

Tags: jquery, traversal, dom-traversal

I'm sure this is very easy but its a friday afternoon and my brain is a little frazzled.

Any help would be appreciated 
I am looking to traverse to an 'a' tag within a 'li' tag.
The li tag has a class of 'menu-item-has-children'.
I am trying to add a class to the 'a' tag.

Here is sample markup

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
<a>Item</a>
<ul>some other stuff</ul>
</li>
```

Any advice on a simple jquery/vanilla approach to doing this??
Thanks :-)

Comment: How you traverse to the `a` would depend entirely on what element you're starting from, ie. the element which raised an event.

Comment: `$('li.menu-item-has-children a').addClass(...)` ?

Comment: This certainly does the trick - problem I have though is there are also 'a' tags in the accompanying 'ul'. Is there a way to only target the first child?

Comment: Yep, use the child operator: `$('li.menu-item-has-children > a').addClass(...)`. Also, just a note on your terminology, this isn't traversal, it's a selector. Traversal is where you have a reference to an element in memory and then use traversal methods to move up/down/aside in the DOM tree to find another related element.

Comment: This did the trick! thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just like the comments say, this should work unless you are trying to get to a specific `a` within a specific `li.menu-item-has-children`, then it would depend on where you are starting from.

```
$('li.menu-item-has-children a').addClass(...)
```